# What is the process of suspending SF user?

Tags: support

What is needed

- votes, how many?
- by whom?
- how does it depnd on scores?
- etc,

for suspending a participant in SF?

Why is it being done anonymously, without any notification and  reasons given?

Comment: I'm guessing you were suspended because you appear to be a puppet account of vgv8...am I correct?

Answer (score 7):

A quick Google search for VGV8 finds a number of very similar incursions into other forums by a user named VGV8 - all characterised by the same question style, rapid escalation to conflict, targeted insults at administrative cabals out to "get newcomers" and a consistent lack of willingness to conform to the norms of whatever site he finds himself on. It's certainly possible that our VGV8 and these are not the same however the similarities are remarkable, right down to his choice of name for his sock puppet alias.

e.g. Message #11 [here](http://www.rususa.com/forum/message.asp-msgid-141) and another [here](http://74.125.95.81/support/forum/p/Web+Search/thread?tid=0792c87308ada296&hl=en) where a user that has an almost identical style exhibits the same patterns seen here. The latter also links to his having been banned completely on other sites. Digging further finds other aliases linked to these that exhibit similar patterns of conflict.

I'm going to stop feeding the Troll now.

Comment: A site full of Geeks and nobody else thought to Google it? +1 for you. -1 for me.

Comment: Oh look, it's a troll on the Internet.  +1 for proving it.

Answer (score 5):

The process is outlined [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) by [Jeff](http://meta.serverfault.com/users/1/jeff-atwood). Basically if someone is constantly being flagged as offensive or spam by other users, they are sent an email by a moderator. If the behavior does not change, the user is suspended. This is only done in extremely rare cases (I've only seen it once - not that I actively look for it though)

It is not done anonymously, it is done by a mod and there is notification given via private email to the offending user.

Answer (score 5):

When someone actually creates enough of a stir to get suspended, they're either actively spamming or have created a huge stir in the number of people they've motivated to flag their posts.

In other words, one person really can't cause this to happen by holding some kind of "grudge".  Like everything on the sites, it's community-driven.